# degree of $f : \mathbb{S}^n \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^n$ with $f(-x) = -f(x)$, where $f \in C^{\infty}$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, spheres

The question I'm about to ask has been asked several times on MSE but none with an answer that involves only degree theory.

I'd like to prove the general case of the exercise in the title without using homology theory, maybe using induction since I managed to prove the case $n=1$ through degree theory on covering spaces, proving that called $\tilde{f}$ the "covering", $\tilde{f}$ satisfies $\frac{1}{2\pi}(\tilde{f}(2\pi)-\tilde{f}(0)) = 2k+1$.

For example, for the case $n=2$, I received an hint to find a regular value whose preimage doesn't intersect the equator line and find an homotpy beetween $f$ and a map with same property.

I don't understand very well this idea so I don't even know whether this idea could be applied only to the case $n=2$ since I'm don't see where it's going.

Any help or direct proof would be appreciated

Comment: Are you comfortable assuming that the degree of the map $x \mapsto -x$ is already known?

Comment: related: http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/eggmath/WY/borsuk-pf.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by degree theory? If you assume something like a lefshetz theorem, then one can get an argument under the assumption that the fixed point set is finite. If $x$ is a fixed point then so is $-x$, and the local degree of the map will either be the same or opposite depending on the parity of $n$ (since either $x \mapsto -x$ is an orientation reversing or preserving diffeomorphism)

Comment: @NickL No, I don't know Lefshetz theorem, what I meant by using degree theory was using basic facts from degree theory, where my degree is defined (when all the hypotesis work) as $\sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \text{sgn}df_{x}$ and it's coincidence $\text{mod}2$ with $\text{deg}_2(f) = |f^{-1}(y)|$ (for every $y \in \text{RegVal}(f)$) and also with closed curve from $\mathbb{S}^{1} \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^{1}$

Comment: @NickL Yes, I know that the antipodal map from $\mathbb{S}^{n} \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^{n} $ is $(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: You should add the assumption that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes didn't mention that, thanks

Comment: No, this is going to be very hard. It's essentially the Borsuk-Ulam theorem (see p. 91-93 of Guillemin and Pollack). Whereas the case of even functions is very easy, the odd situation is quite deep and requires more than just basic definitions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Once proved Borsuk Ulam stated as p.91, is it enough to use it with $f \circ i$ where $i$ is the inclusion of $\mathbb{S}^{k}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ and use multiplicativity of degree ?

Comment: Huh? This is incorrect. Degree makes sense only when dimensions are equal. You have to read about the definition of winding number, and probably more.